# Two-way binding in an angular directive leads to loop

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive with a `select` in it. Here is a cut-down example. Note the real code has more moving parts and some logic.

```
app.directive('numberPicker', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            number: "=model",
        },
        template: "<select data-ng-model='numberName' data-ng-options='name for name in numberNames' class='form-control'></select>",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.numberNames = ["Zero", "One", "Two"];

            scope.$watch('number', function(number) {
                scope.numberName = scope.monthNames[number];
            });

            scope.$watch('numberName', function(numberName) {
                scope.number = scope.numberNames.indexOf(numberName);
            });
        }
    };
})
```

The idea that there is a number in the outer scope which is bound to a `select`. Binding should work both ways.

The problem is that the `$watch`es trigger each other, leading to strange behaviour.

How should I go about binding the scope to a select via a lookup, and the select back to the scope via a reverse lookup?

Comment: Implement one as a function. `scope.number=function() {return scope.numbernames.indexOf(numberName);}`, so no watch is required.

Comment: Does `ng-data-model` work with a function? How does it know when to update?

Comment: Right, ng-model requires assignable expression, you can reverse the function implement scope.numberName as a function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below logic as a work around, but don't think it is an elegant solution

```
scope.$watch('number', function(number) {
    if(scope.numberName != scope.monthNames[number]){
        scope.numberName = scope.monthNames[number];
    }
});

scope.$watch('numberName', function(numberName) {
    if(scope.number != scope.numberNames.indexOf(numberName)){
        scope.number = scope.numberNames.indexOf(numberName);
    }
});
```

Comment: It works, thanks. There must be a general solution this kind of problem though...